# How to handle Comments with Stash in ExpressionEngine?

Tags: templates, comments, dry, expressionengine, expressionengine-stash

What's the best way (DRY) to get the comments of the current entry with stash?

So far I used a embed-template to present all comments and the comment-form. But this does not work within stash — and isn't there a smarter way than a embeded tempalte?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel='news' limit='1' dynamic='on' require_entry='yes' track_views='one'}
…
{exp:stash:set name='entry_comments' parse_tags='yes'}{embed='_interactive/comments' channel='{channel_short_name}' comment_total='{comment_total}' {if allow_comments}allow='yes'{/if}}{/exp:stash:set}
…
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Where are you using {exp:stash:get name="entry_comments"} at?

Comment: Also, I'd say loose the embed if possible for a snippet or Low Variable/Template Variables (add-ons) if one of those are installed.

Answer (score 1):

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/3973821) from Mark Croxton is for an articles listing page that includes comments. It does a bit more than what you're describing in your scenario, but you might be able to use some of the concepts.